# Resultado 'NaN' cuando sumo valores

Tags: jquery

Tengo un script con el que necesito sumar los valores de las columnas, pero me aparece el resultado como NaN.
Necesito sumar de la segunda columna a la sexta.
Me esta cogiendo valores que no son numéricos?

Este es el script:

```
<script>
       var totals=[0,0,0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $dataRows=$("#mytable tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");
            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#mytable td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html(totals[i]);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Este es código PHP:

```
<table id="mytable">
 <thead>
 <tr class="titlerow">
 <th scope="col">Column1</th>
 <th>Column2</th>
 <th>Column3</th>
 <th>Column4</th>
 <th>Column5</th>
 <th>Column6</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <?php
 include("conn.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY name");

 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id']; 
 echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value1']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value2']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value3']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value4']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value5']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 echo '<tfoot>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td>.</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
    </tr>
</tfoot>';
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, si el retorno es **NaN**, es debido a que alguno de los valores no corresponde a un número, o tiene algún problema de formato (`int` como `string` por ejemplo)

Comment: Y si mejor calculas la fila de totales desde PHP en vez de hacerlo con JQuery?

Comment: @Jemonge como? Una vez  generada la tabla con php se puede hacer?

Comment: Puedes calcular esos valores mientras vas creando la tabla. Dentro del while puedes ir sumando los valores y al terminar agregar la última fila con los montos totales obtenidos.

Comment: @GuifIf agregué una respuesta sobre la opción que te mencioné.

Comment: `NaN = Not a Number`  verifica tus asignaciones puede que esten mal estan retornando valores nulos o valores undefined

Comment: El HTML generado con PHP es incorrecto (va a haber `</tr>` sin un `<tr>` de apertura). No sé si es porque lo has reducido para crear un [mcve] o porque es incorrecto de verdad, en cuyo caso, dependiendo del navegador puede que lo _corrija_ y funcione o puede que no funcione como esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomiendo que calcules los valores totales directamente en PHP, no es necesario utilizar JQuery para hacer este cálculo.

El código sería algo así:

```
<table id="mytable">
 <thead>
 <tr class="titlerow">
 <th scope="col">Column1</th>
 <th>Column2</th>
 <th>Column3</th>
 <th>Column4</th>
 <th>Column5</th>
 <th>Column6</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 include("conn.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY name");
$col1 = 0;
$col2 = 0;
$col3 = 0;
$col4 = 0;
$col5 = 0;

 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id']; 
 echo"<tr><td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value1']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value2']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value3']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value4']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value5']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";

  $col1 += $test['value1'];
  $col2 += $test['value2'];
  $col3 += $test['value3'];
  $col4 += $test['value4'];
  $col5 += $test['value5'];
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 echo '<tfoot>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td>Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">'.$col1.'</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">'.$col2.'</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">'.$col3.'</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">'.$col4.'</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">'.$col5.'</td> 
    </tr>
</tfoot>';
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias.